# Extract R, G, B Byte value from TColor

Tags: delphi

In Delphi, is there a ready-to-use function that can extract R, G, B as byte from a TColor variable?

I find the following one online but it seems to be strange:

```
  procedure ColorToRGB(iColor: TColor; var R, G, B: Byte);
    function HexToInt(const Value: string): Integer;
    begin
      Result := StrToInt('$' + Value);
    end;
  var
    s: string;
  begin
    s := IntToHex(iColor, 6);
    R := HexToInt(AnsiRightStr(s, 2));
    G := HexToInt(AnsiLeftStr(AnsiRightStr(s, 4), 2));
    B := HexToInt(AnsiLeftStr(s, 2));
  end;
```

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Graphics.ColorToRGB

Comment: "Ït seems to be strange" is not something we can answer ;-) What is the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `GetRGB()` procedure in the `Vcl.GraphUtil` unit:

`procedure GetRGB(Col: TColor; var R, G, B: Byte);`

```
uses Vcl.GraphUtil;

procedure ColorToRGB(iColor: TColor; var R, G, B: Byte);
begin
  GetRGB(iColor, R, G, B);
end;
```

Comment: Remy, Thank you. Your solution is the perfect one.

Answer (score 12):

The code you have shown is way overkill and inefficient, and it doesn't account for system-defined colors at all, only fixed colors.

Instead, use [`Graphics.ColorToRGB()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.ColorToRGB), which translates a `TColor` (including system colors) into a fixed RGB color value in Win32 [`COLORREF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/colorref) format, and then you can pass that RGB result to [`Windows.GetRValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getrvalue), [`Windows.GetGValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getgvalue), and  [`Windows.GetBValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getgvalue).

```
uses
  ..., Graphics, Windows;

procedure ColorToRGB(iColor: TColor; var R, G, B: Byte);
var
  iRGB: Longint;
begin
  iRGB := Graphics.ColorToRGB(iColor);
  R := GetRValue(iRGB);
  G := GetGValue(iRGB);
  B := GetBValue(iRGB);
end;
```

Comment: Did you mean for `ColorToRGB` to call `ColorToRGB` without qualification?  It's been a long time since I used Pascal, but can Delphi differentiate between two functions with the same name but different argument lists?